# Zoom-in inside circle when radius is changed in Google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have created circle in maps using Google maps API. When I change the radius of circle, the map contents inside the circle must be zoomed in. Pls let me know is der a way to zoom in the contents inside the circle when radius of circle is changed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `var bounds = circle.getBounds()` to get the extent of your circle followed by `map.fitBounds(bounds)` to zoom your map.

Comment: I used the above code suggested by you... But there is one issue, for each radius change the circle is not zoomed. For example., Consider the radius of circle as 200 km. For change of radius to 190, 180 and so on.. the circle should be zoomed.. but in this scenario it is zoomed only for radius is 100,50,25,13,6 and so on... Is der way so that for every radius change the circle is zoomed.. pls let me know... Thanks in Advance